# How can i refresh authentication token generated using chrome.identity namespace?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, access-token, gmail-api

I am creating a chrome extension for gmail. I have generated an access_token to call gmail api. But seems like access token has an expiration time. Will my extension work if the token has expired? If it doesn't, then how can i handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to the API with an expired token will return an error (code 401). In that case, you have to renew the authorization token using [`chrome.identity.getAuthToken`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAuthToken), and try the request again with the new token.

Comment: Trying to regenerate the Auth token. It would be great if anyone guides me on how to fix it.